# Routes chaining in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Using backbone.js, is it possible to chain Url routes?

if I have something like that:

```
routes: {
   "home*splat":"showHomeView",
   "home/view_:param":"handleViewChange"
}
```

I'd like to be able to say something like .../#home/view_gallery and both handlers to fire in the order in which they were declared.

This however, fires only the first handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router runs through the `keys` of `routes` in order, and for the first one that matches, calls the `Router[value].apply(params)`, and then stops.

So, no, URL routes will not chain.  One route per URL hash change event.

Answer (score 0):

This makes for a perfect candidate for a backbone routing plugin that can extend Backbone's already existing Routing mechanism. I am in the process of building one and possibly can open source it when done.